# Teradata Trigger Syntax (referencing similar rows for conditional insert)

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata, database-trigger

I have a `TeraData` table that looks something like this:

```
Name;Year;Amount
1. Bob;2018;20
2. Bob;2022;14
3. Joe;2019;40
4. Ben;2017;12
```

The PK is `Name` and `Year`. I have a trigger in place that prevents a user from editing a row's `Year` to a lesser number. i.e. changing row 3 from 2019 to 2018.

**That trigger is below:**

```
Replace TRIGGER xyz.Month_Update
AFTER UPDATE OF Month ON xyz.table
REFERENCING OLD ROW as OldRow NEW ROW  as NewRow
 FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NewRow.Year < OldRow.Year
abort;
```

Now I would like to do something similar for insert.
I would like to prevent a user from inserting a new row into the table
if..

1. There already exists a row for the same person in the table and
2. That row(s) has a greater year than the one the user is attempting to enter

i.e. User can't enter `Joe;2017;19` but user can enter `Joe;2020;19`

**There are a few obvious problems with the trigger below but it shows the general idea:**

```
Replace TRIGGER xyz.Month_Update
AFTER INSERT ON xyz.table
REFERENCING NEW ROW  as NewRow
 FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NewRow.Year < (select max(year) from xyz.table as t1 where t1.name = NewRow.name group by t1.name)
abort;
```

I'm new to triggers in general and teradata documentation appears porous.. any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly if a Correlated Subquery like this is allowed in a Trigger (and how to write it correctly), but you can use Macros or Stored Procedures in a Trigger:

```
REPLACE MACRO xyz.Month_Insert_macro(yr INT, name VARCHAR(50)) AS
( ABORT 'Greater year already exists for that name'
  WHERE :yr <
    ( SELECT Max(yr) FROM xyz.table
      WHERE name= :name
    );
);

Replace TRIGGER xyz.Month_Insert
-- it's better to abort BEFORE the Insert than AFTER (same for your Update Trigger)
BEFORE INSERT ON xyz.table
REFERENCING NEW ROW as NewRow
FOR EACH ROW
   EXEC xyz.Month_Insert_macro(NewRow.yr, NewRow.name);
```

Comment: Yeah using a correlated subquery had eluded me thus far. I've debated using a Stored Procedure but I'll give your Macro solution a try